# How to stick to bottom on layout by using CSS?

Tags: css

I made my site layout, like under plunker.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/maBAxf?p=preview)

```
.bottom_block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

It's left sidebar has bottom block like above code, but it doesn't work.
It doesn't stick to bottom.
How can I stick to bottom?

Comment: Use position: fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this line

```
  <div class="bottom_block left-sidebar-down">
```

then change it to

```
  <div class="bottom_block">
```

and go to your style.css and find bottom_block class and change it to

```
.bottom_block {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #996666;
}
```

that should work for you.

Comment: If I use `fixed`, its width is expanded.

Comment: simply add you custom width , like width: 400px or whatever! changed my code again you can use it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position fixed and left, right to simulate the 100% width like this:

CSS:

```
.container_fixed{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}

.bottom_block {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container_fixed">
    <div class="bottom_block"></div>
</div>
```

here the example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/1nmemzew/

I hope this will be helpful

Regards

Comment: It works like footer. I want to make it limit specific width.